# Inline text and extended background

Tags: html, css, text

The goal is that the red part in the [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobaiasjl/pen/avRxvj?editors=110) reaches to the left end.

- The problem is I cannot add more html, cause it comes from our cms.
- The line widths have to be dynamic.
- The background is a little bit transparent.

I've tried the hack with the box-shadow, but this is depending on the line width.

```
div {
  padding: 0 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

p {
  top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 
    17px 0  0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.9),
    -200px 0 0 rgba(255,0,0, 0.5);
}
```

You should look at the [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobaiasjl/pen/avRxvj?editors=110) to fully understand the question:

Comment: something like this? [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOJGqO) or you want the `box-shadow` underneath the white background which contains the text?

Comment: Your codepen has different results in the two browsers. Which one did you have in mind? For the one, simply changing -200px to -500px is enough. But your question sounds like you're only testing on the other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `:before` pseudoselector with a linear gradient.

```
p:before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 37px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 37px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    background-size: 100% 50px;
    left: -500px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 500px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

This requires no modification to your existing p style.

If you're unsure how wide the red labels need to be, you can set `left` and `width` to a very large number, and set `overflow: hidden;` on your container div.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaPdZg?editors=110

Answer (score 1):

How about a repeating background on the div?

```css
div {
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0 500px;
      width: 300px;
      background-color: green;
      background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, green 0%, green 12%, #804000 12%, #804000 88%, green 88%, green 100%);
      background-position:0 10px;
      background-size:500px 50px;
      background-repeat:repeat-y;
    }

    p {
      top: 10px;
      padding: 10px 0;
      bottom: 20px;
      line-height: 50px;
      display: inline;
      background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 
        17px 0  0 0 rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    }
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Abusing transform with this "solution": http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbqNXN?editors=010

A rectangle is created with a pseudo, positioned where your current box-shadow is and then it's expanded 100x towards left (note the `transform-origin` that avoid expanding towards right)
`overflow: hidden` on parent avoid seeing the disast... overflow :)

```
div {
      overflow: hidden;
}
p:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: -100%; right: 100%;
  transform-origin: right center;
  transform: scaleX(100);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: the background is wrong. there should be one for each line. look at the answer above.

Comment: After having seen your codepen on Chrome, k. Both your pen and accepted answer doesn't repeat either on Firefox